# ASP.NET - Get the value of environment variables passed with docker

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, docker, environment-variables

In my `docker-compose.yaml`, I'm setting environment variables to an api service with

```
env_file:
      - db.env
```

`db.env`

```
MYSQL_DATABASE=db_name
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_USER=user
MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
```

How to access them to connect to the database with a string like this?

```
string _connectionString = $"server={Env["MYSQL_SERVER_NAME"]}; database={Env["MYSQL_DATABASE"]}; user={Env["MYSQL_USER"]}; password={Env["MYSQL_PASSWORD"]}";
```

Comment: Use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYSQL_SERVER_NAME")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an invaluable reference: [Configuration in .Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration) - essentially, a lot of the plumbing is already done for you.

So, if for example you wanted to set that in your startup `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
....
string _connectionString = $"server={builder.Configuration["MYSQL_SERVER_NAME"]}...
```

With DI, in a MVC controller for example:

```
public class SomeController: Controller
{
   public SomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      string _connectionString = $"server={configuration["MYSQL_SERVER_NAME"]}....
```

In a Razor Page:

```
public class HelloModel: PageModel
{
    public HelloModel(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
       string _connectionString = $"server={configuration["MYSQL_SERVER_NAME"]}....
```

Hth..